# How does my site know what button I clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, imagebutton

'

I have a problem with my site in ASP.NET. My applications contains a few buttons (imagebuttons) that are able to change. For example: When I press an empty button I want to be able to put a picture and a website in it. I've made this possible with a popupbox.

The problem where I'm running into:

When Im trying to give button 2 a image and a website, it gives button 1 a image and website because I told it in:

```
 public partial class Ingelogd : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Image1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (DropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "Youtube")
        {
            Btn_1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Youtube.png";
            Btn_1.PostBackUrl = ("http://www.youtube.com");
            Btn_1.OnClientClick = "";
        }
        else
        { 

        }

    }
```

Now I actually want the same for Btn_2 , but then I have to write the exact same code but change Btn_1 to Btn_2. This is impossible to do because I want 19 website ( youtube but also facebook, twitter etc.) Im also going to have 19 buttons ( currently I only have Btn_1 and Btn_2). This would mean I have to make 19*19 = 361 pieces of code. I assume there is a way to make a sub program for this. My teacher also told me I could use cookies for the buttonclick, but I have no idea how to make a cookie with a Imagebutton.

**What is the best solution to solve this problem?**

I also have the ASP.NET Code here for you who wants to see that code aswell.

```
    <title>Ingelogd</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
            //-->
        </script>
<style type="text/css">
            #popupBoxOnePosition{
                top: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 120%;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); display: none;
            }
            .popupBoxWrapper{
                width: 550px; margin: 50px auto; text-align: left;
            }
            .popupBoxContent{
                background-color: #FFF; padding: 15px;
            }  


</style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Dit is de pagina als je ingelogd bent.
    </div>
    <div id="popupBoxOnePosition">
            <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
                <div class="popupBoxContent">
                    <h3>Instellingen</h3>
                    <p>Kies uit een van de volgende links.</p>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem >Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem >Youtube</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem >Facebook</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="Button1" runat="server" 
                    OnClick="Image1_Click"/>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button_afsluiten" runat="server" Height="48px" OnClientClick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');return false;" Text="Afsluiten" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="Btn_1" runat="server" Height="48px" OnClientClick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');return false;" 
 ImageUrl="" />
 <asp:ImageButton ID="Btn_2" runat="server" Height="48px" OnClientClick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');return false;" 
 ImageUrl="" />


   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add attributes to DropDownList and to use it. For example add two new attributes ImageUrl and SiteUrl. Your code should look:

```
protected void Image1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
{
    Btn_1.ImageUrl = DropDown.Attrubutes["ImageUrl"];
    Btn_1.PostBackUrl = DropDown.Attrubutes["SiteUrl"];
    Btn_1.OnClientClick = "";
}
```

Comment: This is probably so the user can add an image and site url himself? But that is actually not what I want. The user has to choose between standard sites.

Comment: User checks standard sites in your DropDownList, every item in your DropDownList should contains two new attributes, for example ImageUrl and SiteUrl, that you will use

Answer (score 0):

I've never used asp, but most of those code is just plain c#, so I should be good.
Make 19 separate functions, one for each button, and dynamically add the Image and Url instead of using ifs:

```
protected void Image1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
{
    String val = DropDown.SelectedItem.Value;
    Btn_1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + val + ".png";
    Btn_1.PostBackUrl = "http://www." + val + ".com";
    Btn_1.OnClientClick = "";
}
```

If you want 1 function for all buttons as well, you'll have to give all your buttons a `Name` and check the senders name inside the function.